# Set child element attr using an attribute of the parent using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got the following html:

```
<ul id="clients-strip">
    <li>
    <a href="http://example.com/case-studies/" data-colour="/images/made/assets/images/article-images/client-colour.png">
        <img src="/images/made/assets/images/article-images/client-grayscale.png" alt="Client" width="59" height="35">  
    </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

and need to basically swap the  img src with the parent 'a' elements "data-colour" attribute when the 'a' element is hovered over (i'd like to fade out the old att and fade in the new too)

My jquery is not going too well :(

```
$('ul#clients-strip li a').hover(function(){
        $(this.' img').attr('src', this.data-colour);
    });
```

Any ideas as to what i'm doing wrong? Also, is it even going to be possible to essentially fade out one image and fade in another in the way that i'm trying here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do

```
$('ul#clients-strip li a').hover(function(){
    //get the child image and change the src
    $('img', this).attr('src', $(this).data('colour'));
});
```

If you wan't to return to the original src when leaving you could do

```
var cacheSrc;
$('ul#clients-strip li a').hover(function(){
    cacheSrc = $('img', this).attr('src');
    //get the child image and change the src
    $('img', this).attr('src', $(this).data('colour'));
},
function(){
    $('img', this).attr('src',cacheSrc);
});
```

Comment: Nicola, yours works great! Do you have any idea how i can get them to fade each transition?

Comment: @bjohnb that's much harder, you should have two images and hide() one and  fadeIn() the other, but you should change your markup

Comment: That is what i tried originally but for some reason i can't fathom is making all the images group together. I think this will be fine for now i'll work on the two image method for another day! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

i'm pretty sure "this" on

```
$(this.' img').attr('src', this.data-colour);
```

returns an object.

Try with

```
$(this).children('img').attr('src', this.data-colour);
```

or maybe

```
$(this).closests('img')
```

or maybe

```
$(this).children().eq(0)
```

where 0 is the index of the object in the array returned

Check the JQuery api

Comment: Note: .closest() finds ancestor, not a child.

Answer (score 1):

This answer doesn't use JS I really feel like you should just be using CSS Sliding doors instead for this technique. You're hovering on a link - that I assume is part of a menu - and loading images in that format will just cause the browser to hang for a second while it loads the image.

I'd recommend a technique that is described here: http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-css-menu-using-image-sprites, basically just set a class and background sprite to the whole menu and change the background image postion on hover. This will load faster and prevent the flicker while the image loads.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this.data-colour with $(this).attr('data-colour'), I think that should work. Also you have to backup the original src to get it back after hover.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul#clients-strip li a').hover(function(){
 var source = $(this).data('colour');
 var $a = $(this);
 $('img',this).toggleFade(function(){
   $a.data('colour',$(this).attr('src'));
   $(this).attr('src',source);
   $a.toggleFade();
 });
});
```

Comment: I recommend @mikevoermans solution, as the data-colour img will not be loaded into browser cache on page load, and will cause a delay.  You Might get away from a 'hang' through the fade timeout.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, haven't tested it but the idea is there.

```
$('#clients-strip li a').hover(function(){
    var a = $(this);
    $(this).find('img').fadeOut(500, function(){
        $(this).attr('src', a.attr('data-colour')).fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attribute name is not accessible e.g `this.data-colour` will be translated to a mathematical expression when accessing from javascript :

Therefore you should use  `$(this).attr('data-colour')` instead of `this.data-colour`

**Remember `-` dash is actually minus operator**

```
 $('ul#clients-strip li a').hover(function(){ 
            var toggleWith= $(this).attr('data-colour');
            $(this+' img').attr('src', toggleWith);   
        });
```

Although `- dash` is [valid html name attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#NT-Name) when accessing from javascript  enclose it in quotes